# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getError") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, wcf

I'm trying to consume an API through a PHP class using PHP Soap, but everytime I try to I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getError") is not a valid method for this service in /home4/eleven11/public_html/comtrade.com.mx/testing/facturacion-prueba/Models/clsGenerarFacturaXML.php:151 Stack trace: #0 /home4/eleven11/public_html/comtrade.com.mx/testing/facturacion-prueba/Models/clsGenerarFacturaXML.php(151): SoapClient->__call('getError', Array) #1 /home4/eleven11/public_html/comtrade.com.mx/testing/facturacion-prueba/Models/clsGenerarFacturaXML.php(151): SoapClient->getError() #2 /home4/eleven11/public_html/comtrade.com.mx/testing/facturacion-prueba/Controllers/facturas_controller.php(16): clsGenerarFacturaXML->timbrar_cfdi('../XML/prueba.x...', '00001') #3 {main} thrown in /home4/eleven11/public_html/comtrade.com.mx/testing/facturacion-prueba/Models/clsGenerarFacturaXML.php on line 151

This is my Code:

```
public function timbrar_cfdi($ruta, $referencia)
{
    //PREPARAMOS LAS PROPIEDADES PARA LLAMAR EL SERVICIO
    $usuario = "DEMO130227LA7";
    $password = "TJaufp55";
    $xml = file_get_contents($ruta);

    if ($xml == false) {
        return "ERROR";
    }

    //Instanciamos el servicio
    $client = new SoapClient('http://timbrado.facturarenlinea.com/WSTFD.svc?wsdl');
    $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

    //Agregamos una validación
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) { echo 'Error en Constructor' . $err ; }

    //Declaramos los parametros de entrada
    $param = array('usuario' => $usuario,'password' => $password,'cadenaXML' => $xml,'referencia' => $referencia);
    $result = $client->call('TimbrarCFDI', $param);

    //Declaramos que no muestre Warnings, se debe configurar en el PHP.ini
    error_reporting(0);

    //Validamos la respuesta
    if ($client->fault) {
        return "FALLIDO";
    } else {    // Chequea errores
        $err = $client->getError();
        if ($err) {
            return "ERROR";
        } else {
            $xmlResult = $result->XMLResultado;
            $fecha = $result->Timbre->FechaTimbrado;
            $uuid = $result->Timbre->UUID;
            file_put_contents("../XML/" . $uuid . ".xml", $xmlResult);
            return json_encode(array("UUID" => $uuid, "fecha" => $fecha));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `getError()` is not valid :D Maybe `$client` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Hahahaha you were right... I used nusoap instead of PHP Soap and it worked, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. The most braincracking mistakes tend to be the most simple also :)

Comment: If you use nusoap library, change soapclient() to nusoap_client().